# Can't find IIS config file listed by appcmd

Tags: windows, iis, configuration, iis-8.5, appcmd

I'm managing a bunch of IIS 8.5 servers and I'm working on complying with security baselines.

My question is this: If I run a specific `appcmd` query on one of our IIS servers, I get the following:

```
C:\>appcmd list config -section:system.web/authentication
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms requireSSL="true">
      <credentials>
      </credentials>
    </forms>
    <passport />
  </authentication>
</system.web>

C:\>
```

What I need to do is find the actual configuration file that `appcmd` is reading from here, so I can update the relevant section manually (updating using `appcmd` itself causes all kinds of problems). I can't find it. I've checked the following files so far:

- %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
- %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
- %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
- %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
- %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
- %WEBROOT%\web.config
- %WEBROOT%\old application path\web.config
- new application path\web.config

I can't think of any other places to look. Most of those files don't even have a `<system.web>` section and none of them have the word "credentials" in them anywhere.

Where is `appcmd` reading from to generate the output above?

---

### Edit:

I'm still looking into this, and just found the following [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e01fc50a(v=vs.100).aspx), which might be the answer:

> **Default Configuration**
>
> The following default credentials element is not explicitly configured in the Machine.config or root Web.config file. However, it is the default configuration that is returned by the application.
> `<credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />`

Answer (score 3):

Check:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
```

System.web is a dot.NET setting, so it should be in the global web.config file, it seems it is only in the 64bit version, not the 32bit framework.

Comment: Upvoted as a good place to check, not accepted as it isn't the right answer in this case. I added both the file you suggest and the machine.config in the same folder as places I've already checked.

Comment: When I change the `system.web/authentication` settings in the GUI, it changes the file I mentioned. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I'm looking for the `<credentials>` element specifically. Can you change that element in the GUI? If so, where?

Comment: Can you edit your question to state what you are actually try to achieve? What settings do you want to change/add?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is an understanding of how this works so I can write an intelligent request for a waiver for the security and compliance team. They keep saying "just edit the file" and I'm like "just tell me what file to edit" and they don't know and I can't find it either.